# Firebase - check if value exists in database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If the user is authenticated the first time I want to create a new database entry. Therefore I want to to check if the user has already an entry. I searched for some examples but my solutions are not working. My callbacks are never called. Any ideas?

```
    if (firebaseUser == null) {
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, AuthActivity.class), 123);
    } else {
        final DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase
                .getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("users")
                .child(firebaseUser.getUid());

        database.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: ye");
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: fuuu...");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCancelled: " + databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Instead of creating database records for a particular user after signing in, you could do it at the time of creating account, this way every registered user will have a record. Also, add a `firstLogin` field and set it to false and whenever someone signs in, check the value stored there, if it is false, do some actions(Ex - show tutorial) and set the value to true.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria you are right. Thanks. Nevertheless this should working.. or? ;)

Comment: Well I have never used Firebase on Android so can't tell.